# how to connect database from different server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, localhost, database-connection

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCon" connectionString="Data Source=sys1-PC; Server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; Database=entmx001; Uid=root;Pwd=root_mysql; Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
```

> this is my connection string in webconfig file.Now i want to connect my code to the database which is on other computer.what changes do i need to make here.or what else do i need to do..plzzhelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" name="MyCon" connectionString="Data Source=name_of_your_server;Initial Catalog=name_of_your_db; User Id=user_id;Password=password;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: its not coming... datasource will be the name of computer from which i want to use the database.??

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I've fixed example